# how does bloom works for any plateform

Tags: ros, bloom-release, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If i release my custom ros package using bloom software release tool which i build in ubuntu local pc with intel processor. How is it possible that this package also runs on other plateforms where i install that package with apt install ros-package ? Also how is it possible that given ros package runs on any plateform without cross compilation?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/362917/how-does-bloom-works-for-any-plateform/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2020-10-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

bloom just puts the source code version you release into a release repository. from there it is fetched from a build server which builds the binaries for the different platforms. Whatever you build locally is completely independent...

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2020-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2020-10-06**:
It means if i release the ros package or even any software using bloom and the binaries will work in any platform like raspberry pi, jetson nano etc?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2020-10-07**:
well, no. They need to compile successfully for that arch.
I think (but might be mistaken) by default it builds for the following architectures:

- amd64
- i386 (prior to lunar, this has been dropped as Ubuntu itself isn't shipping i386 binaries anymore)
- armhf / arm32
- arm64

See [REP-3](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html) for additional information.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Expanding on @mgruhler's answer, Bloom processes ROS packages and generates content specific to each target *operating system* (Examples: Debian Buster, Fedora 32, and Ubuntu Focal). For packages released into the official ROS distributions, that data is then used to build packages for each supported target / architecture (Examples: amd64, i386, armhf, arm64).
Bloom itself does not have or perform any architecture-specific functions.

> Also how is it possible that given ros package runs on any plateform without cross compilation?

Packages are built in a native environment for each target platform. On the ROS 1 build farm, those native environments are provided by custom Docker images which include qemu-user-static binaries for emulating the native platform. Which is one reason why those builds tend to require more time. On the ROS 2 build farm we are using native ARM machines to provide the armhf and arm64 builds.

---

Originally posted by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) with karma: 906 on 2020-10-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1